# 1994 Tracker Emergency Brake

Tags: electrical, brakes, chevrolet

I have a problem with the emergency light ((!)) staying on, just started 2 days ago when I went over a speed bump, Brake fluid is full, I topped it up a month ago, the gas task was close to empty so I filled up, but the light stayed on.  The light goes out when I first take the emergency brake off(after starting) the it comes back on and stays on.  The weather has been below freezing.  What other sensors are connected to the emergency brake light ((!))

Answer (score 2):

The proportioning valve will turn the light on, it's a small block that the brake lines run into just below the master cylinder. Should be a single wire running to a connector, unplug it and see if the light goes out. If so you probably have air in one of the lines causing the valve to be off center.